# Windows Installer Automation and Installshield Basic MSI: Mystery String during Chained MSI

Tags: hash, windows-installer, installshield

**EDIT:** Turns out the mystery string was a simple MD5 hash of the name of the file (including the extension and capitalization).

I'm attempting to automate the process of creating a Chained MSI through InstallShield. In the GUI, this involves going to `Releases`, adding a chained package, linking to the MSI and streaming the file into the project.

I've reverse engineered what exactly happens behind the scenes by analyzing the project file as XML. It essentially just comes down to table edits. I understand you can use Windows Installer Automation to open an `*.ism` file and access the database tables ([LINK](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?109074-Direct-Editor-through-Automation-objects)).

Yet, there is a single field in the ISChainPackageData table which I cannot seem to generate or figure out how it was calculated. It is the column titled, `File`. It is a 32 character hex string preceded by an underscore. I have discovered that the only attribute that determines this field is the name of the MSI file being streamed. For example:

Linking to a chained MSI by the name of `Test.msi`, yields `_29B31F67F21C9EE77CBF8C4C5D24ACE9`.

Changing the name would change this. Changing the file, including replacing it with an empty file of the same name, does not.

I believe it is some kind of simple hash of the name, but I haven't had any luck guessing it.

Does anyone have any insight on what they might be using here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. It's a hash-based GUID of a combination of a few things. I'd have to trudge up the code to find out exactly what, but it's at least the relative path and filename, and possibly something related to the package in question (probably its primary key value).

This is used to generate a unique key for each file you include with a package, without allowing duplicate files. (Windows Installer doesn't like backslashes in its primary keys.) The actual value here isn't meaningful; if you're careful to avoid duplicate keys and don't overlap file path and name combinations, you can probably put in any valid key value you like. However that may prevent the IDE from detecting duplicates itself.

Comment: Interesting. When you say IDE, I believe you're referring to InsallShield? I'm hoping to simply generate a regular GUID and manually make sure that there aren't any duplicate files (though this isn't something that is likely to happen in this specific case). If I gather correctly from what you're saying, would it be reasonable to assume this won't have any bad effects on the behavior of the resultant MSI? (Thanks for the detailed reply!)

Comment: Correct. If you open a modified project and try to add a duplicate file, it may let you if the key was generated differently. But as long as you avoid that, I don't foresee problems at run time. If there are collisions, it's probably just a question of which file lands second.